# Pandas dataframe manipulating with long string column to 2 columns dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have dataframe:

| id | greetingsname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hello+peter|goodbye+john |
| 2 | hi+cheff|gutentag+rudolf|goodafternoon+Alex |

and i want

| id | greeting | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hello | peter |
| 1 | goodbye | john |
| 2 | hi | cheff |
| 2 | gutentag | rudolf |
| 2 | goodafternoon | Alex |

I dont know, how dynamically split column greetingsname, to get what I want, because column greetingsname has different string lengths. But the delimeter distribution remains the same `greeting DELIMETER(+) name DELIMETER(|) greeting DELIMETER(+) name`

And in this sense it can have different lengths (several names and greetings and in another column a different number of names and greetings)

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use explode for this:

```
df['greetingsname']=df['greetingsname'].apply(lambda x: x.split('|'))

res=df.explode('greetingsname')

print(res)

   id       greetingsname
0   1         hello+peter
0   1        goodbye+john
1   2            hi+cheff
1   2     gutentag+rudolf
1   2  goodafternoon+Alex

res[['greeting', 'name']] = res['greetingsname'].str.split('+', expand=True)

del res['greetingsname']

res.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print(res)

   id       greeting    name
0   1          hello   peter
1   1        goodbye    john
2   2             hi   cheff
3   2       gutentag  rudolf
4   2  goodafternoon    Alex
```

Answer (score 3):

We can try `extractall`

```
df.set_index('id')['greetingsname']\
  .str.extractall(r'(?P<greeting>[^+|]+)\+(?P<name>[^|]+)').droplevel(1)
```

---

```
         greeting    name
id                       
1           hello   peter
1         goodbye    john
2              hi   cheff
2        gutentag  rudolf
2   goodafternoon    Alex
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this regex works?

Comment: @tayfunyiğit Sure. I'll edit the answer with the explanation of regex.